# Convert Permission Mask to Roles for GetPermissionCollection

Tags: java, sharepoint, permissions

We have a requirement where we need to check if a user has "Upload" access to a folder in Sharepoint document library. For that, I am using the "GetPermissionCollection" method of Permissions webservice on the document library. The response I get is of below format:

I am not able to convert the Permission mask to role. I am doing this in Java and I dont have SPBasePermissions class.

Is there a way in Java to convert the Mask into role?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just need to do bitwise operations against it.  You will need to hardwire the bitmask for the permissions you care about, but this should be safe enough since these do not change in SharePoint 2010.

Comment: can you provide details?

Answer (score 0):

I found this link:
[Permission/Deny Mask in SharePoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920551/permission-deny-mask-in-sharepoint/4320497#4320497)
which says something about this bitwise AND.
You should also use this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd304243%28PROT.13%29.aspx

which Enums the Masks for the permissions.

I also made an javascript example that can help you...
however you will have to convert it into java

I used JQuery, SPServices js (http://spservices.codeplex.com/)
and this link for the masks codes
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd304243%28PROT.13%29.aspx
I Hope this helps you, I did this because I was needing it also, however it may also help others.

You need to replace the LIST NAME HERE with the name of the list, and find out which is the mask for upload.

The script will spit everyone that has access to a list, and say if they can read, add, change and delete things. Hopes this helps you.

```
$('#divid').html('Working...').SPServices({
    operation: "GetPermissionCollection",
    objectName: 'LIST NAME HERE',
    objectType: "List",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        var out = "<ul>";
        $(xData.responseXML).find("Permission").each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr("MemberIsUser") === "True") {
                out += "<li>User: " + $(this).attr("UserLogin") + "</li>";
            } else {
                out += "<li>Group: " + $(this).attr("GroupName") + "</li>";
            }
            var readmask = 0x0000000000000001;
            var addmask = 0x0000000000000002;
            var editmask = 0x0000000000000004;
            var deletemask = 0x0000000000000008;
            out += "<li>Mask: " + $(this).attr("Mask") + "</li>";
            var canread = readmask & $(this).attr("Mask").toString(16) > 0 ? "Yes" : "No";
            var canadd = addmask & $(this).attr("Mask").toString(16) > 0 ? "Yes" : "No";
            var canedit = editmask & $(this).attr("Mask").toString(16) > 0 ? "Yes" : "No";
            var candelete = deletemask & $(this).attr("Mask").toString(16) > 0 ? "Yes" : "No";
            out += "<li>Can Read: " + canread + "</li>";
            out += "<li>Can Add: " + canadd + "</li>";
            out += "<li>Can Edit: " + canedit + "</li>";
            out += "<li>Can Delete: " + candelete + "</li>";
        });
        out += "</ul>";
        $('divid').html(out);
    }
});
```

Comment: That last line of completefunc needs a # in the DIV id:
                 $('#divid').html(out);