# Operator && cannot be applied

Tags: c#, .net

I am testing an example snippet that I found as an answer on [another Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920551/permission-deny-mask-in-sharepoint/4320497#4320497)

However the compiler is spitting out this "Operator && cannot be applied to operands of type long and bool".
Why does it do this? As I read the code, it says "If mask and permission are greater than 0 return success bool"

Am I reading this wrong?

(Also, no one called it out as a bad example so I expected it to work. Not that I am a copy-paste coder)

```
bool CheckMask( long Mask, long TestPermission ) {
    return Mask && TestPermission > 0;
}

long mask = 4611686844973976575;

const long MASK_ViewListItems = 0x0000000000000001;
bool HasPermission_ViewListItems = CheckMask(mask, MASK_ViewListItems);
// HasPermission_ViewListItems is true

const long MASK_UseClientIntegration = 0x0000001000000000;
bool HasPermission_UseClientIntegration = CheckMask(mask, MASK_UseClientIntegration);
// HasPermission_UseClientIntegration is false
```

There are an awful lot of similar questions on StackOverflow and I've clicked through most of them, there's a big list to my right as I type. None have applied to my situation, at least I was able to see the relation between the answers and my problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're using [`&&` (conditional AND, only valid for `bool` operands)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx) instead of [`&` (bitwise AND, valid for `bool` operands or integer operands)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx) - I suspect you want the latter, and you should also use brackets due to precedence rules. I'd change the parameter names to follow .NET naming conventions, too - and make it static as it doesn't rely on any state:

```
static bool CheckMask(long mask, long testPermission)
{
    return (mask & testPermission) > 0;
}
```

You might also want to change to using an enum instead of `long`:

```
[Flags]
public enum Permissions
{
    ViewListItems = 1 << 0,
    ...
    UseClientIntegration = 1 << 9
}

static bool CheckMask(Permissions mask, Permissions testPermission)
{
    return (mask & testPermission) != 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very informative - ended up learning a fair bit of about bit shifting implementing these ideas.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing this is what you want:

```
(Mask & TestPermission) != 0
```

So, you need:

- a bitwise `&` (instead of `&&` that applies only to bool)
- and I'm guessing you want to check if any bit is set including the sign bit (so `!=` instead of `>`).